# Thor YAML.load_file invalid subclass (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, yaml, thor

I'm creating a thor script that shows the current project I am on based on a yml file that stores Ruby structures.  I'm getting an error when I tried to load this yml file.

```
from /Users/cpara/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `node_import'
from /Users/cpara/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
from /Users/cpara/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
from /Users/cpara/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:146:in `block in load_file'
from /Users/cpara/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:145:in `open'
from /Users/cpara/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:145:in `load_file'
from ./project:84:in `current'
from /Users/cpara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/cpara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /Users/cpara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
from /Users/cpara/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from ./project:213:in `<main>'
```

Here is the piece of the script I'm trying to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'yaml'
class Project < Thor
  include Thor::Actions

  # Task: return current project
  desc 'current', 'Shows current project.'
  def current
    projects = YAML.load_file "#{ENV['HOME']}/.hana/data/projects.yml" #error
    abort "There are no projects.  Try creating one first." if not @projects.is_a? Array
    projects.each do |project|
      if project.current == true
        say_status :current, "Current project: #{project.name} // #{project.type} // #{project.version}", :green
        return project
      end
    end
    say_status :error, "There is no current project.", :red
  end
end
```

I've triple checked the path in irb and it does exist.  I thought it was the way my YAML was storing my Ruby structure but even the console, I get the error.  Here is my YAML file

```
--- 
- !ruby/struct:Proj 
  name: test
  type: testing
  version: 4.0.2
  deploy_dir: deploy
  source_dir: source
  current: true
```

Any ideas?  I'm running Ruby 1.9.2p318.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML is trying to instanciate a **Struct** named **Proj** from the file as indicated by the line:

```
!ruby/struct:Proj
```

You should require the file where you haved defined Proj before loading the yaml. Or, just to test if it works, in your code, after the *require 'yaml'* line define Proj:

```
Proj = Struct.new(:name, :type, :version, :deploy_dir, :source_dir, :current)
```